# Is it somehow possible to check if points `x` and `y` is in a line when only the y-intercept and the slope is given?

Tags: java, int, geometry, line

Is it somehow possible to check if a random point is in the line if there is only the slope and the `y-intercept` given? (`f(x)= ax + b` and `a` and `b` is given)

Comment: Fill in everything in the formula and check if there’s a contradiction or not?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But this has **nothing** to do with `java`. This is a mathematics question, and belongs on [math.se] Stack Exchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a mathematics question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, however, this has nothing to do with programming and is more of a mathematical question. (I would recommend going here https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Solving this using basic Algebra, given the slope and y-intercept we can check if a point is on a line by substituting the x and y values.  For example, if we had a given slope of -3 and a y-intercept of 2, we would get the following equation of *y = -3x + 2*, if we wanted to check if the point (2, 3) was on the line we would substitute the x and y value. So it would be *3 = -3(2) + 2*, and if you were to do the math you would get 3 = -4, which isn't true.  If it ended up as 3 = 3, then the point would indeed be on the line.

As I saw Java in one of the tags for the question, I will also give this solution in code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.printIn(CheckPoint(-3, 2, 2, 3));
    }

    private static bool CheckPoint(float slope, float yInt, int x, int y)
    {
        //Standard form for line is y = ax + b
        if(y == (slope * x) + yInt)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We would also sometimes (but not necessarily) use something like `if (abs(y - f(x)) <= SOME_EPSILON)` instead of `if (y == f(x))`. (But it all depends on what's actually being done. Just blindly doing epsilon tests everywhere can lead to stuff like e.g. objects in a simulation getting stuck in each other.)